# Permissions set to 777 and file still not writeable

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I have set file permissions to 777 yet I cannot write to the file with PHP.

I can clearly see in my FTP client that the file has 0777 permissions and when I do:

```
echo (true === is_writable('file.txt')) ? 'yes' : 'no';
```

I get 'no';

I also tried:

```
echo (true === chmod('file.txt', 0777)) ? 'yes' : 'no';
```

With the same result.

The directory listing goes something like this:

```
public_html
    public          0777
        css         0755
        js          0755
        file.txt    0777
```

And I'm using .htaccess file to redirect all traffic to the public subfolder. Of course, I have excluded the file from rewriting (it is accessible from the browser I checked):

```
RewriteRule  ^(file).*  - [L]
```

Why is that?

Comment: Do you have write permission to the folder?

Comment: Could you provide the directory listing of the file? Is it possible you aren't the owner? Also, it may be an FTP server configuration problem.

Comment: Why are you doing the === operator?

Comment: Can you write to the file using a normal text editor or terminal command (touch)?

Comment: @Daniel A. White: The === operator also checks type equality, since we already know that is_writable returns a bool, then it should be the same effect as using ==

Comment: so why not is_writable('file.txt') ? 'yes' : 'no' ?

Comment: It's just my habit. I try to make all my conditional statements absolutely clear so you can see what value and what data type is to be expected just by looking at the condition.

is_writable returns boolean data type so that's why I use ===. The == operator would understand 1 as a boolean true, too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess Apache runs as a different user/group than the user/group owning the file. In which case, the file itself needs to be `0777`.

`public` only needs to be `0777` if you plan on adding files to the folder using PHP. Even if the folder itself is not `0777`, if the file is and the folder has at least `5` for the user (`read/execute`), you should be able to write to the file.

In the end, your file tree should look like this:

```
public_html
    public
        file.txt  0777
```

Naturally, you won't be able to change those permissions using PHP, but you can do so from your FTP client.

If it still isn't working, PHP might be running in safe mode or you might be using an extension such as PHP Suhosin. You might get better result changing the owner of the file to the same user/group that is running the script.

To get the user/group id of the executing user, you may use the following:

```
<?php
echo getmyuid().':'.getmygid(); //ex:. 0:0
?>
```

Then, you may use `chown` (in the terminal) to change the owner of the file:

```
> chown 0:0 file.txt
```

Comment: Actually it is a shared hosting environment so I don't have access to the shell. But thanks for very helpful answer anyways.

I have decided to modify my script so it uses database to write the data to instead of text files. Now it works.

Comment: I just want to add that I've set correct owner and my files were still not writable. The cause was SELinux as explained in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/9819118/2522817

Answer (score 2):

In opencart i faced this error after installing vqmod and giving all necessary permissions.

after researching a bit, found it.

"MODS CACHE PATH NOT WRITEABLE" is actually refering to vqmod folder itself and not the cache folder.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 vqmod
```

in your root directory.....

Answer (score 1):

You have to chmod the file right after you create it.

```
function Doo_Chmod($path, $chmod = null)
{
    if (file_exists($path) === true)
    {
        if (is_null($chmod) === true)
        {
            $chmod = (is_file($path) === true) ? 644 : 755;

            if (in_array(get_current_user(), array('apache', 'httpd', 'nobody', 'system', 'webdaemon', 'www', 'www-data')) === true)
            {
                $chmod += 22;
            }
        }

        return chmod($path, octdec(intval($chmod)));
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: I uploaded the file. I didn't create it in PHP.

Comment: Do this: var_dump(get_current_user()); is the current user the same as the FTP user that uploaded the file? If no, that is your problem, you need to CHMOD it with the FTP client and then you can use the function I posted above (or manual CHMODs for that matter).

Answer (score -1):

Not strictly related to the above question, still, I will put it here for future visitors, as I came here reading the title.
From [arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/File_permissions_and_attributes#File_attributes):

> ### File attributes
>
> Apart from the file mode bits that control user and group read, write
> and execute permissions, several file systems support file attributes
> that enable further customization of allowable file operations. This
> section describes some of these attributes and how to work with them.
>
> ***Warning**: By default, file attributes are not preserved by cp, rsync,
> and other similar programs. chattr and lsattr*
>
> For ext2 and ext3 file systems, the e2fsprogs package contains the
> programs lsattr and chattr that list and change a file's attributes,
> respectively. Though some are not honored by all file systems, the
> available attributes are:
>
> ```
> a: append only
> c: compressed
> d: no dump
> e: extent format
> i: immutable
> j: data journalling
> s: secure deletion
> t: no tail-merging
> u: undeletable
> A: no atime updates
> C: no copy on write
> D: synchronous directory updates
> S: synchronous updates
> T: top of directory hierarchy
> ```
>
> For example, if you want to set the immutable bit on some file, use
> the following command:
>
> `# chattr +i /path/to/file`
>
> To remove an attribute on a file just change + to -.

For a file, with no additional attributes, the `lsattr` looks like this:

```
$ lsattr /etc/hosts
-------------e- /etc/hosts
```