# File not writeable even though permissions are 777

Tags: php, apache, filesystems

Something really weird is going on.

`httpd.conf` says apache runs as the apache user.

I have chown-ed the files to be `apache:apache`.

The file is still not writeable.

I have set the permissions (of the entire webroot as a last resort) to be `777` and the file is still not writeable...

The path is correct because `file_exists()` is `true` but `is_writeable` is `false`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this on linux? Do you have SELinux enabled?

Comment: Is this on linux? Is your webroot on something different than ext2/3/4?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's more than possible that you have SELinux running on the machine. To check whether it's running or not you should be able to run the `getenforce` command on the commandline. If it returns "Enforcing" then SELinux is enabled and running in enforcing mode.

I'd suggest that in most cases (unless you want to spend days learning about SElinux) that you disable it by running `setenforce Permissive` and editing `/etc/sysconfig/selinux` so that next time the server restarts it won't reactivate it.

If you're sure you don't need SELinux you could just remove the packages from the server

Comment: Thanks. I wish I sucked up my pride and asked this last night :/

Comment: Vamooooooo, te quiero

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you are root on vserver only?
Do you have own server or do you have only host>
If you have only host (not whole machine) than often you can't run vmstat or edit file of sysctl .

Second option is SELinux. Run **getenforce**. If it returns **enforcing** than you should run **setneforce Permissive**. This dissable SELinux