# Can't read & execute a file (with 777 permissions and correct user / group) on CentOS 7

Tags: php, apache, centos, chmod, chown

I have the following problem i want to install a shop system on a google cloud compute instance so i installed the required things like apache, mysql, php etc.

Now i have a problem with the permissions.

```
<?php echo exec("whoami"); ?>
```

returns that i'm currently running as apache

The file has as chown apache (and also as groupe apache, apache:apache) and also 0777 permissions.

But if i call the file with is_writeable the answer is: false
(I can only read not execute or write)

Any idea?

Comment: Where is the file located? Do you have selinux enabled?

Comment: I have solved this problem - Answer found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9819032/file-not-writeable-even-though-permissions-are-777/9819118#9819118